# Div Positon Relative To Cursor Coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image gallery with a custom context menu. When I right-click on the image the menu position is relative to the cursor coordinates.

If the coordinates + the div size are > the window size, the position of the div changes and the div should be inside the img.

When I click in the image and the coordinates + div size are <  window size, there is no problem. The problem is when I click where the coordinates + div size are >  window size, sometimes it works great and sometimes the div position seems not follow jvascript conditions. I don't get it.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zee9jxeg)

Here's the code:

```
gary.addEventListener('contextmenu', gallery);
function gallery(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var reh=e.clientY;
    var rey=e.clientX;
    var cnx=conxm.clientHeight;
    var cxm=conxm.clientWidth;
    var gig=window.innerHeight;
    var fgi=window.innerWidth;
    if((reh+cnx)>=gig && (rey+cxm)<=fgi){
        conxm.style.top=((gig-cnx)-10)+"px";
        conxm.style.left=rey+"px";
    }
    else if((reh+cnx)<=gig && (rey+cxm)>=fgi){
        conxm.style.top=reh+"px";
        conxm.style.left=((fgi-cxm)-10)+"px";
    }
    else if((reh+cnx)>=gig && (rey+cxm)>=fgi){
        conxm.style.top=((gig-cnx)-10)+"px";
        conxm.style.left=((fgi-cxm)-10)+"px";
    }
    else{
        conxm.style.top=reh+"px";
        conxm.style.left=rey+"px";
    }
    conxm.style.display="block";
}

<div id="curtain">
    <div id="txt">
    </div>
    <div id="rev">
        <img src="../img/revi.png" onClick="rvs()">
    </div>
        <img src="" name="gary">
    <div id="frw">
        <img src="../img/reviv.png" onClick="fwd()">
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** The function works if both width and height are defined for the div, but I need the width to be variable.

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zee9jxeg/

Answer (score 0):

At the end I simply moved

```
conxm.style.display="block";
```

before

```
e.preventDefault();
```

and now it works perfectly!